# How to user INNER JOIN to recieve first name of user with a student id in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables student and result
I have been trying to display the first name of a student when viewing result records.

The table student has fields studentid and firstname

The table result has fields studentid,assessmentid and grade

I have tried the following using INNER JOIN but cant seem to link the students first name and their student id to show the results

```
SELECT result.assessmentid student.firstname, result.date_submitted
FROM result
INNER JOIN student
ON result.studentid=student.studentid;
```

Can anyone see the problem?

EDIT: Sorry about not formatting the code thanks to who ever did it

Comment: Try again with a LEFT JOIN

Comment: Essentially your query only works should you have a `student` record with a matching id as that of it's counterpart record within the `result` table.

[Read more](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) about inner joins.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a comma here: `result.assessmentid student.firstname`

Comment: @redelschaap your answer _may_ solve the initial problem, but actually may not be the right solution since a left join will present NULL values from the right-hand table, where the OP may want non nullable data from said table. therefore in the OPS question it's somewhat ambiguous because we don't know ultimately what they're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I am able to do it now. I will also read up on those tutorials thanks again.

Comment: @NotSooNoobish Is the missing comma in the real code? I get a syntax error when I leave it out.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem? You should post some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: The above does not work but is missing a comma like jpw said.

After the comma was put in it now works and shows the desired output of retrieving the student name using the student id from the result table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are missing a comma between result.assessmentid and student.firstname that should make the syntax invalid and throw an error...

Another other possible issue is that you use an inner join which will filter out students without results. If you want all students regardless then use student as main source and left join result like this:

```
SELECT result.assessmentid, student.firstname, result.date_submitted
FROM student
LEFT JOIN result ON result.studentid=student.studentid;
```

Comment: I suspect the missing comma is a copying error, because you can't have `.` in an alias -- it causes a syntax error.

Comment: @Barmar Oh right, I thought maybe MySQL allowed that although I've never seen it before (but MySQL does some odd things :) )

Comment: The question says he's trying to display the student's name when showing result records. So why would he need to show students with no results?

Comment: The missing comma actually solved the problem but thanks for helping out!

Comment: @Barmar With the added comma the query looks like it should work with the inner join, but I added the left join part to explain the possible difference in output.